# Can a local proxy 'improve' network reliability?

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, envoyproxy, istio

Apologies for the fairly vague question but I have been working with [Envoy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/) as part of [Istio](https://istio.io/) recently and was wondering about one of the benefits of sidecar proxies in general

By configuring a proxy locally (as Istio does) in the same network namespace as an application container (such as a website) to intercept and proxy traffic to and from the application, could the network reliability be improved? I'm thinking if the proxy handles network traffic 'better' in some way it may be able deal with networking issues better whilst the application itself would only need to handle a much more reliable local connection between itself and the proxy.

I guess the kernel would be responsible for most of the networking work so maybe it makes little difference, but is there anything a proxy can do (not necessarily Envoy specifically) that could improve network reliability?

Comment: with istio you have envoy as sidecard container, mainly to have the mtls and so on, with istio you have control all of aspect of the service traffic

Comment: yeah so I was wondering with that in place are there benefits around network reliability with Envoy sitting in between

Comment: from here you take a look of all benefits that you can have with envoy https://www.envoyproxy.io/learn/circuit-breaking

Comment: yeah I'm aware of a lot of the benefits of Envoy as well a circuit breaking, I was wondering whether there were any of the nature I alluded to in the question